# How to set the OVR Boundary's guardian grid walls visible in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

In Unity can you set the actual grid walls of Oculus' guardian visible? When I use OVRBoundary.SetVisible(true), only a flat outline of the guardian's area appears on the ground. But I would like to set the gridded walls of the boundary visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour of Oculus guardian, you cannot override this. The walls will be shown only when you're close to them. If you want to display the walls you can do it yourself.

OVR gives you GetGeometry method, you can use those points to change the shape of mesh to make it work as you want. Then you can put material on it to make it look however you like